# Using jQuery variables to store HTML/PHP tags

Tags: php, jquery, html, tags, append

I am making a website using jQuery mostly, and PHP to communicate with local database.

Basically this is the skeleton of my webpage (HTML/PHP):

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <script type = "text/javascript" src = "script.js"></script>
</head>

  <body>
    <div id="content">
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

And using the following code for jQuery:

```js
$(document).ready(function()
{
  
  var tagsQuery = "<? include 'connection.php'; $sql = 'SELECT dateofsale, eid, cid, amount FROM Sales'; $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql); if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) { echo '<table><tr><th>Fecha</th><th>Vendedor</th><th>Cliente</th><th>Monto</th></tr>'; while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) { echo '<tr><td>' . $row['dateofsale'] . '</td><td>' . $row['eid'] . '</td><td>' . $row['cid'] . '</td><td>' . $row['amount'] . '</td></tr>';} echo '</table>';}else {echo '0 results';}?>";
  
  $('#content').append(tagsQuery);

});
```

So in summary, I am storing HTML/PHP tags in a variable in jQuery and appending this tags to the content div. It works when the page is loading for the first time but not when I click other buttons to display this same data (for example if I navigate to a page where this code runs, it does not work entirely...it only partially works.

Could you help? Let me know if I wasn't clear enough. Thanks!!

PS: conntection.php only connects to the database.

Comment: You cant run php code on the clients system. You need to save the php file on the server and look into running an AJAX request through jquery with your required data to query the database.

Comment: Don't do you php code that way. There is no good reason to have all that code in one line, inside the `var tagsQuery`. Just do your php code, and just echo the final code inside the `var tagsQuery = ...`

Comment: This is not good practice to use PHP code inside jQuery and specially including files and all insdie javascript/jQuery.... You can use the AJAX to getting the same response and append that response to perticular div....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PHP must be processed on the server, and by the time you're running jQuery in the browser, the server is no longer in the picture. Your best bet is probably to put your "tagsQuery" code into a PHP script and call it using [AJAX](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/), API-style:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $.ajax('http://example.com/new_php_script.php')
        .done(function(data){
            // "data" is the resulting output of the PHP script
            $('#content').append(data);
        });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you are appending this code when the page is loaded, why don't you just put this code inside php tags? Javascript is only for client side scripting. You can't change the server code from a web browser. You can easily put that code inside an php tag if you want

```
<?php your php code here ?>
```

This way you can do the task you are about to achieve

Comment: This is not good practice to use PHP code inside jQuery and specially including files and all insdie javascript/jQuery.... You can use the AJAX to getting the same response and append that response to perticular div.... First check the way they write there code.... This is not good way to answer you can comment in there question....

Comment: No, you can write the php code inside the content div. Not in the script part

Comment: See what i mentioned is "This is not good practice to use PHP code inside jQuery and specially including files and all insdie javascript/jQuery...."

Answer (score 0):

You can also do something like this,if u want to append your design to previous div

```
$(document).ready(function()
    {
     var html = '';
     html += '<div class="item col-xs-12 col-lg-6">';
     html += '<div class="thumbnail">';
     html += '<div class="caption">';
     html += '<h4 class="group inner list-group-item-heading">';
     html += '<b>'+data.subject+'</b></h4>';
     html += '<h5><b>'+data.projectname+'</b></h5><br />';
     $('#content').append(html);
    });
```